# How do I create a custom view controller transition that is interruptable/cancellable?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have a small custom view controller (it's a menu) I'm presenting, and I want you to be able to halt the presentation half way through if you change your mind.

Per [this WWDC 2016 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/), doing so should be pretty easy and just require the implementation of `interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating`, and return, say a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.

However I'm not finding this to be the case. If I return my property animator there, and programmatically call my view controller to be dismissed half way through the transition, it waits until the animation is ***fully concluded*** for the dismiss animation to occur. It won't interrupt.

*Note: this is with a "normal" animation controller, not an interactive one. Per the video this should be fine, it's not inherently an interactive transition"

I set up my corresponding controllers as shown:

```swift
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return MyMenuAnimationController(type: .presentation)
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return MyMenuAnimationController(type: .dismissal)
}

func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return MyMenuPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
}
```

```swift
class MyMenuAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    enum AnimationControllerType { case presentation, dismissal }
    
    let type: AnimationControllerType
    
    var animatorForCurrentSession: UIViewPropertyAnimator?
    
    init(type: AnimationControllerType) {
        self.type = type
    }
    
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 5.0 // Artificially long for testing
    }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        if type == .presentation, let myMenuMenu: MyMenuMenu = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) as? MyMenuMenu {
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(myMenuMenu.view)
        }
        
        interruptibleAnimator(using: transitionContext).startAnimation()
    }
        
    func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
        if let animatorForCurrentSession = animatorForCurrentSession {
            return animatorForCurrentSession
        }
        
        let propertyAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), dampingRatio: 0.75)
        propertyAnimator.isInterruptible = true
        propertyAnimator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let isPresenting = type == .presentation
        
        guard let myMenuMenu: MyMenuMenu = {
            return (isPresenting ? transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) : transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)) as? MyMenuMenu
        }() else {
            preconditionFailure("Menu should be accessible")
        }
        
        myMenuMenu.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: myMenuMenu)
        
        let initialAlpha: CGFloat = isPresenting ? 0.0 : 1.0
        let finalAlpha: CGFloat = isPresenting ? 1.0 : 0.0
        
        myMenuMenu.view.alpha = initialAlpha
        
        propertyAnimator.addAnimations {
            myMenuMenu.view.alpha = finalAlpha
        }
        
        propertyAnimator.addCompletion { (position) in
            guard position == .end else { return }
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            self.animatorForCurrentSession = nil
        }
        
        self.animatorForCurrentSession = propertyAnimator
        return propertyAnimator
    }
    
    private func calculateTranslationRequired(forMyMenuMenuFrame myMenuMenuFrame: CGRect, toDesiredPoint desiredPoint: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        let centerPointOfMenuView = CGPoint(x: myMenuMenuFrame.origin.x + (myMenuMenuFrame.width / 2.0), y: myMenuMenuFrame.origin.y + (myMenuMenuFrame.height / 2.0))
        let translationRequired = CGVector(dx: desiredPoint.x - centerPointOfMenuView.x, dy: desiredPoint.y - centerPointOfMenuView.y)
        return translationRequired
    }
}
```

And a simple presentation controller:

```swift
class MyMenuPresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

But as I said, if I present it simply and then 1 second into the 5 second animation I dismiss it (signifying someone tapping outside the view controller to dismiss it mid transition), nothing occurs until the animation is done. It's as if it's queued up, but won't execute until the presentation is completed.

```swift
let myMenuMenu = MyMenuMenu()
present(myMenuMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
    myMenuMenu.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Am I misunderstanding a core part of the custom view controller transition flow? Do I have to make it an interactive transition? Something else? In the event that an interactive transition is required, where do I update the interaction controller in my code with progress? With a gesture it's obvious, but this is just a "fade 0 alpha to 1 alpha" animation.

Comment: Not sure about this, but I think you have to tell the transitionContext that the transition is canceled.

Comment: @dasdom Calling `dismiss` wouldn't automatically handle that?

Comment: Not sure about that. My feeling is: No.